# One to many relations in linq-to-sql

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

I'm writing a small application using ASP.NET MVC just for fun of it, but I have problem grasping how to design one particular variant of one to many relations. Since I'm using LinqToSQL I guess it's more about designing the tables than my C# code, but I'm mentioning it in case the way the data is to be used might affect the design.

The thing I'm having problem with is this:

Let's say I want to make a book database and let's say each book can have multiple names assigned to it (for example translations of the title). One of the titles needs to be the main one.

What seems to be the obvious solution for me, would be to make a table for books and another table for the names. Names get a BookId column and books get a MainNameId column and on top of that foreign keys are set, so when the models are generated in my application, the relations are set correctly off the bat.

However my logic fails as I won't be able to add a book without having a title first and I won't be able to add a title without having related book in the database first. Adding a book to the database was suppose to also add the first (and main title).

Anyway, I can think of a few workarounds for this problem, but I was wondering what's the proper way to solve this.

Comment: You could give it a default title(main one) then add new title later.

Comment: I suggest you to use Entity Framework. There are several reasons. First, it can handle your issue. Second, it was said five years ago on ADO.NET blog that ["Entity Framework will be our recommended data access solution for LINQ to relational scenarios."](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/10/29/update-on-linq-to-sql-and-linq-to-entities-roadmap.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you have to save both records to 2 tables at the same time.
EntityFramework can do it for you in 1 save changes or you may add first a record to the book table and then to the names table and do "Save changes" for both of them at the same time.

this code should do it:

```
public class Book
{
    public string BookId { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BookNames> Names { get; set; }
}

public class BookNames
{
    public string BookId { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }

}

public class Functions
{
    void createBook()
    {
        Book new_book=new Book();
        new_book.ISBN = "RandomISBN";
        new_book.Names = new IEnumerable<BookNames>() {
            new BookNames{BookName = "The Good Book", Language = "ENG"},
            new BookNames{BookName = "El buen libro", Language = "SPN"}
        };

        dbcontext db = new dbcontext();
        db.Books.Add(new_book);
        db.SaveChanges();

    }
}
```

Comment: Something like this would even work with linq to sql (saving multiple related records to the database at the same time). I was asking about how to handle cross related tables, but it seems impossible.